# any one know better then curl function in php i need help

Tags: php, curl

anybody know the replacement of `curl` function in php

```
$ch = curl_init($connect_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$curl_scraped_page = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $curl_scraped_page;
```

Comment: Perhaps you can describe your problem or concern, rather than just asking for a replacement.  I have always found curl very very powerful and useful, but either way, if you say what your trouble is, we can help you solve the problem, rather than try to blindly give you solutions that likely won't actually be what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use socket connection functions available in php.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php

Comment: is socket connection more efficient??

Comment: below link may answer your question, http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/12687-curl-vs-socket

Answer (score 1):

If allow_url_fopen = 1 (in your php.ini):

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://example.com/index.html');
```

or

```
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "r");
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem you are trying to solve? Curl unavailable? Is safe mode enabled? Something else? Have you tried using the http stream wrappers? e.g.

```
return file_get_contents($connect_url);
```